# Open query - incorrect syntax next to passed in variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, openquery

I'm running this query

```
      SET @Qry = ' SELECT [MLSTQT] INTO ##DISPENSED_LOCATION' 
              +' FROM OPENQUERY(MA,''SELECT MLSTQT FROM ES3.MD.MOC   WHERE MLWHSL='''+    @ProcessOrder+''' '')'
        EXEC (@Qry)
```

And I'm getting an error saying that there is incorrect syntax next to the value @ProcessOrder.

What's wrong with my query?

Seems it would be  WHERE MLWHSL='10000' which is correct.

Comment: apostrophe inception.... Use this:  `MLWHSL=''''+    @ProcessOrder+'''''')'`

Comment: Thank you Cha! That worked!

Comment: a small advice from me: Use `PRINT @Qry` to see what is getting passed to the `EXEC` function if you encounter these problems in future

Comment: Thanks that's actually really useful, I didn't think of that. Thanks Cha.